# Do We know if our mathematics enough to describe nature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematics

To the extent, if you make a postulate based on the observation that can not be described with classical mechanics, this is how quantum mechanics was initially put in and then we ask what's its prediction? what's are the result? What's is predicted and then we again do an experiment and then check the theory and formalism and mathematics associated with it. It looks like there are no violations as far we know but as we can not prove a theory with a hundred percent and there may be certain regions where the theory may break down in some domain, We don't know. Now the question is whether Mathematics is sufficient? Do We Know if the math is sufficient to an extent when we go to a regime where we include quantum field theory, general relativity plus quantum mechanics?

---

It may look like that there is no definite answer to it but I want to know if there is a good Answer.

Edit: It's closed as opinion based and I'm satisfied with you to some degree. But I think there can be a good answer with our modern knowledge of science. I don't think that this is based on opinion.

Comment: This question while it may not be fit for site, I think is highly interesting. I guess the real answer is that there is no textbook solutions where we can check if our answers are 'correct'. It may just be that nature works in a completely different mechanistic way than we expect  it but still it produces same result.. i.e: a black box

Comment: Since we currently don't have a complete description of nature (aka ToE) at our disposal, we obviously don't know whether the math we've discovered is sufficient to formulate it or not. Once we do have such a description, we will have formulated the necessary math in the process anyway. Therefore, this question is meaningless

Comment: What I mean here is, Is it possible that to describe nature in such a regime we need to do measure changes in our description of space and time?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi everything we have learned in the last 30 years in looking for a TOE seems indeed to indicate that we need to change our description of space and time to achieve this. String theory and loop quantum gravity are such attempts.

Comment: Think of Newton when he made up with his mechanics.
Before that time differential calculus was not yet available.
So Newton also invented this calculus on the way.
Without these tools it was impossible to write down
even the basic concepts (like $\mathbf F=m\ddot{\mathbf r}$).
May be physics is in a similar situation now again.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch That's the way we can see how we describe nature with math. Because the words we use to communicate are not enough to describe it. Like for duality etc. So I'm asking is there a limit to this language itself that the reason We are not able to tackle the problem at a deeper level?